# Get T-SQL value using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following string in database:

```
SET @Value = "[4888378977CA4A5] Test String"
```

Also, the `@Value` may also have 'RE: ' at the start of the string such as:

```
SET @Value = "RE: [4888378977CA4A5] Test String"
```

How can I access the `4888378977CA4A5` part of the string using regular expressions?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using for regex?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, 'RE: ' may also sometimes appear at the start of the string (this is going to be an email subject which needs detecting). I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL doesn't have native regex support. You can use [a CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) to access .NET regex functionality or use [PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) if the pattern is simple.

Or if you just want to get the contents of `[...]` maybe [CharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) would work.

```
;with strings as
(
SELECT 'no match' AS string UNION ALL
SELECT '[4888378977CA4A5] Test String' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RE: [Other Value] Test String' 
)
select substring(string,
             charindex('[',string)+1,
             charindex(']',string, charindex('[',string))-charindex('[',string)-1)
                                                                          AS result
from strings
where string like '%/[%/]%' ESCAPE '/'
```

Returns

```
result
-----------------------------
4888378977CA4A5
Other Value
```

Comment: it's not regex, but its resolved my issue, so thanks Martin :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) is a way to do it in SQL Server 2000 using VBScript.RegExp.

However, in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 you would be better off using a the .NET Regex Library, as illustrated in [here](http://anastasiosyal.com/archive/2008/07/05/regular-expressions-in-ms-sql-server-using-clr.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be `\[([A-Z0-9]+)\]`. Extracting the substring in the captured group depends on your regex flavor. It could be `$1`, `\1`, `match.groups(1)` etc.